# How to include a column of progress bars within a QTableView?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview, qprogressbar

I started creating a Plugin on QGIS 3 and my plugin requires Progress bars within a QTableView. I am trying to figure out how to add a column of progress bars within my QTableView in PyQt5. But I couldn't find any relevant code or resources regarding my problem.

My Table

[image]

```
        w= self.tasklist_tabv
        delegate = ProgressDelegate(w)
        w.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, delegate)

        w.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["ID", "Name", "Progress"])

        for r, (_id, _name, _progress) in enumerate(data):

            it_id = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(_id)
            it_name = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(_name)
            it_progress = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            chkBoxItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            chkBoxItem.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            chkBoxItem.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            it_progress.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole+1000, _progress)
            w.insertRow(w.rowCount())

            for c, item in enumerate((it_id, it_name, it_progress)):
                w.setItem(r, c, item)

            for c, item  in enumerate((it_id, it_name, chkBoxItem)):
                w.setItem(r, c+1, item)

class ProgressDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
def paint(self, painter, option, index):
    progress = index.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole+1000)

    opt = QtGui.QStyleOptionProgressBar()
    opt.rect = option.rect
    opt.minimum = 0
    opt.maximum = 100
    opt.progress = progress
    opt.text = "{}%".format(progress)
    opt.textVisible = True
    QtGui.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ProgressBar, opt, painter)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a delegate:

## QTableView:

#### - PyQt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

data = [("1", "Baharak", 10), ("2", "Darwaz", 60),
        ("3", "Fays abad", 20), ("4", "Ishkashim", 80), 
        ("5", "Jurm", 100)]

class ProgressDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        progress = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1000)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionProgressBar()
        opt.rect = option.rect
        opt.minimum = 0
        opt.maximum = 100
        opt.progress = progress
        opt.text = "{}%".format(progress)
        opt.textVisible = True
        QtWidgets.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ProgressBar, opt, painter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    delegate = ProgressDelegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, delegate)
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 3)
    model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["ID", "Name", "Progress"])
    for _id, _name, _progress in data:
        it_id = QtGui.QStandardItem(_id)
        it_name = QtGui.QStandardItem(_name)
        it_progress = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        it_progress.setData(_progress, QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1000)
        model.appendRow([it_id, it_name, it_progress])
    w.setModel(model)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### PyQt4

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

data = [("1", "Baharak", 10), ("2", "Darwaz", 60),
        ("3", "Fays abad", 20), ("4", "Ishkashim", 80), 
        ("5", "Jurm", 100)]

class ProgressDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        progress = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1000)
        opt = QtGui.QStyleOptionProgressBar()
        opt.rect = option.rect
        opt.minimum = 0
        opt.maximum = 100
        if hasattr(progress, 'toPyObject'):
            progress = progress.toPyObject()
        opt.progress = progress
        opt.text = "{}%".format(progress)
        opt.textVisible = True
        QtGui.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ProgressBar, opt, painter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QTableView()
    delegate = ProgressDelegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, delegate)
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 3, w)
    model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["ID", "Name", "Progress"])
    for _id, _name, _progress in data:
        it_id = QtGui.QStandardItem(_id)
        it_name = QtGui.QStandardItem(_name)
        it_progress = QtGui.QStandardItem()
        it_progress.setData(_progress, QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1000)
        model.appendRow([it_id, it_name, it_progress])
    w.setModel(model)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

## QTableWidget:

#### - PyQt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

data = [("1", "Baharak", 10), ("2", "Darwaz", 60),
        ("3", "Fays abad", 20), ("4", "Ishkashim", 80), 
        ("5", "Jurm", 100)]

class ProgressDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        progress = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1000)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionProgressBar()
        opt.rect = option.rect
        opt.minimum = 0
        opt.maximum = 100
        opt.progress = progress
        opt.text = "{}%".format(progress)
        opt.textVisible = True
        QtWidgets.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ProgressBar, opt, painter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 3)
    delegate = ProgressDelegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, delegate)

    w.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["ID", "Name", "Progress"])
    for r, (_id, _name, _progress) in enumerate(data):
        it_id = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_id)
        it_name = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(_name)
        it_progress = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        it_progress.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1000, _progress)
        w.insertRow(w.rowCount())
        for c, item in enumerate((it_id, it_name, it_progress)):
            w.setItem(r, c, item)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### PyQt4

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

data = [("1", "Baharak", 10), ("2", "Darwaz", 60),
        ("3", "Fays abad", 20), ("4", "Ishkashim", 80), 
        ("5", "Jurm", 100)]

class ProgressDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        progress = index.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1000)
        opt = QtGui.QStyleOptionProgressBar()
        opt.rect = option.rect
        opt.minimum = 0
        opt.maximum = 100
        if hasattr(progress, 'toPyObject'):
            progress = progress.toPyObject()
        opt.progress = progress
        opt.text = "{}%".format(progress)
        opt.textVisible = True
        QtGui.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_ProgressBar, opt, painter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QTableWidget(0, 3)
    delegate = ProgressDelegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, delegate)

    w.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["ID", "Name", "Progress"])
    for r, (_id, _name, _progress) in enumerate(data):
        it_id = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(_id)
        it_name = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(_name)
        it_progress = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
        it_progress.setData(QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1000, _progress)
        w.insertRow(w.rowCount())
        for c, item in enumerate((it_id, it_name, it_progress)):
            w.setItem(r, c, item)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: I'm getting an error and I'm not able to come out with a proper solution to it. Please help me out!

Comment: https://imgur.com/lBP6uP8

@eyllanesc

This is the error I'm getting. I've updated the code in my question for your reference.

Comment: I've also tried using int(progress), but no success.

data = [("1", "Baharak", 60)]

Comment: PyQt 4 and QGIS 2.14 @eyllanesc

Comment: python2 or python3??

Comment: Python 2.7 @eyllanesc

Comment: @SumanthReddy okay, I know where the problem is, wait a moment

Comment: @SumanthReddy I have updated my code, try my updated solution

Comment: I'm getting the same error, even after I updated the code @eyllanesc

Comment: @SumanthReddy have you add `if hasattr(progress, 'toPyObject'):
            progress = progress.toPyObject()`?

Comment: test the problem try changing: `option.progress = 10`

Comment: @SumanthReddy delete this code: `for c, item  in enumerate((it_id, it_name, chkBoxItem)):
                w.setItem(r, c+1, item)`

Comment: No error if I try `option.progress = 10`

and I also removed the checkbox code. @eyllanesc

Comment: @SumanthReddy I think the error is caused by the line that tells you to eliminate, now try testing the code that updates

Comment: Sure, will do @eyllanesc
Please let me know when the code is updated.

Comment: I did not see any change in the code, did you update it ? Please let me know if you updated it @eyllanesc

Comment: Please respond...I think you forgot to update the code @eyllanesc

Answer (score 1):

add this to your code

```
self.progressbar = QtWidgets.QProgressbBar()
self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(0, 2, self.progressbar)
```

Later you can add progress to your progressbar by

```
self.progressbar.setValue(int)
```