# How to get functional combobox in QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qcombobox, qstyleditemdelegate

As the title suggests I'm looking to get a combobox in a QTableView.
I've looked at several other questions that deal with comboboxes in tableviews, but they mostly concern comboboxes as editors and that is not what I'm looking for.

I would like  the combobox to be visible at all times and get its data from the underlying model. It doesn't have to set data in the model.

I tried to adapt this example of a progress bar delegate: [How to include a column of progress bars within a QTableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54285057/how-to-include-a-column-of-progress-bars-within-a-qtableview)
Leading to this code:

```
class ComboDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        combo = QStyleOptionComboBox()
        combo.rect = option.rect
        combo.currentText = 'hallo'  # just for testing
        combo.editable = True
        combo.frame = False
        QApplication.style().drawComplexControl(QStyle.CC_ComboBox, combo, painter)
```

But this gives me a greyed out, non functional combobox.

[image]

How do you get a functional combobox there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, the `paint()` function only *draws* a combobox, it does not create one.

If you want a persistent widget set for an item, and that widget doesn't need to update the model, then you should use [`setIndexWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget).

A basic implementation on a *static* model could be like this:

```
class SomeWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.table.setModel(someModel)
        for row in range(someModel.rowCount()):
            combo = QComboBox(editable=True)
            combo.addItem('hallo')
            self.table.setIndexWidget(someModel.index(row, 2), combo)
```

If the model can change at runtime (and is possibly empty at startup), then you need to connect to the [`rowsInserted`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) signal:

```
class SomeWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.updateCombos()
        someModel.rowsInserted.connect(self.updateCombos)

    def updateCombos(self):
        for row in range(self.table.model().rowCount()):
            index = someModel.index(row, 2)
            if self.table.indexWidget(index):
                continue
            combo = QComboBox(editable=True)
            combo.addItem('hallo')
            self.table.setIndexWidget(index, combo)
```

Then you can access any combo based on the index row:

```
    def getComboValue(self, row):
        index = self.table.model().index(row, 2)
        widget = self.table.indexWidget(index)
        if isinstance(widget, QComboBox):
            return widget.currentText()
```

<sup>Remember: whenever you're studying the documentation, you *must* also review the documentation of **all** inherited classes. In this case you should not only read the docs about QTableView, but also the whole inheritance tree: QTableView > [QAbstractItemView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html) > [QAbstractScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html) > [QFrame](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html) > [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) > [QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) and [QPaintDevice](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintdevice.html).</sup>

Comment: @musicamente. Thanks for your elaborate answer. This should help me a long way. You're right that paint() suggests only drawing, but the 'editable' and 'currentText' properties of QStyleOptionComboBox made me think that it was possible to get a functioning combobox that way. When do those properties get used?

Comment: @mahkitah A [QStyleOption](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoption.html#details) is an object that "contain[s] all the information that QStyle functions need to draw a graphical element". Standard Qt widgets don't usually draw themself on their own, but "ask" the current QStyle to draw in a consistent way, and style functions use the style option to know some specific widget features: long story short, in your case you were telling the style to *draw* a combobox that *looks* editable and with a text displayed as the current. You can read more on https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/style-reference.html